# Strange beahior using select() combine with pipe() and fork()

Tags: c, linux, unix, process, pipe

Given the following snippet:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/select.h>


int main() {
    int io[2];
    pipe(io);
    int read_end = io[0], write_end = io[1];

    int cpid = fork();
    
    if(cpid == 0) {
        close(read_end);
        sleep(1);
        return 0;
    } else {
        //close(write_end);
        timeval timeout = {5, 0};

        fd_set readfds;
        FD_ZERO(&readfds);
        FD_SET(read_end, &readfds);

        int ready = select(read_end + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
        printf("ready? %d", ready);
    }
}
```

If the snippet is run as it is. the programm will block 5 seconds. select wait for the read-end of the pipe to be ready to read some data, which never happens and the timeout is reached.

But if I uncomment `close(writeend);` in the parent process just after the fork, then select stop blocking (returning '1', not '-1', which is the file descriptor of the read-end) once the child process terminated.

I don't understand the later behavior. I thought i would have to use `pselect` to wait for both data on the read-end of the pipe or the parent process receiving a SIGCHLD, as suggested in the documentation: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html

> The pselect() system call allows an application to safely wait
> until either a file descriptor becomes ready or until a signal is
> caught.

Any insights ?

Edit: you can try it using: https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/online-compiler/

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details about the behavior you want to achieve. When you create a pipe in the parent process, after `fork` both ends of the pipe are open in both processes. Every process should close the unused end before using the pipe. As long as the parent has the write end open and does not `write`, `read` will block. If you close it both in the parent and the child (implicitly on exit), `read` will detect EOF. When `select` returns it only means that a subsequent `read` will not block. `read` will return 0 when the write end of the pipe was closed by all processes

Comment: @G.M. I read this section of the documentation but 1) does multi-threaded account also for multi-process application? 2) What changes the behavior is not that I'm closing the file descriptor used by select (the read-end) from the child process, but that i'm closing another file descriptor (the write-end) from the very same parent process prior the call to select.

Comment: @Bodo "If you close it both in the parent and the child (implicitly on exit), read will detect EOF." That was the part I was missing! I understand what happens now, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed by Bodo in t the comment:

> If you close the write-end of the pipe both in the parent and the child (implicitly on exit), read will detect EOF.

Explains why select stop blocking when the write-end is closed in the parent process and the child process terminates (and so close its write-end of the pipe)

If the write-end is not closed in the parent process a call to read would still block in the parent process even after it was closed in the child and so `select` would continue to block.

The part I was missing is that when all write-ends of a pipe are closed, read detect EOF and does not block anymore.